# How to store access_token for more requests on API (Python)

Tags: python, api, python-requests, access-token

I am making API requests via Python's 'requests'-module. I am getting the access_token, which is a Bearer token.
I've put the token into a variable like this:

```
def get_token():
    url = 'https://myapiurl.com/oauth/token'
    payload = {'username':'myusername', 'password':'mypassword'}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'origin': 'https://blabla.com'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers)
    mytoken = r.json()['token_type']
    mytokentype = r.json()['access_token']
    token_param = str(mytoken) + ' ' + str(mytokentype)
    return token_param
```

The output is a string that has this structure:

```
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhb.....0sImF6cCI6ImVCOEdI
```

I need this structure for the following GET requests where this access_token is required. I don't want to get a new token everytime I make a new GET-request.

I have issues in finding out how to:

**1: store an access_token**

**2: check if the access_token is valid**

**3: use this token to make other GET requests on my API.**

I am very thankful for any advice.

Comment: One solution would be to save the access_token in a global variable (if you are not using any database) and then use it with all your get requests until it expires. Upon expiration,when making a request it'll give you corresponding error, on getting this error call the `get_token()' function again for new token.

Comment: Yes, that helped, thank you.

Store token in global variable `complete_token`:
`result_accesstoken = result["access_token"]
result_tokentype = result["token_type"]
complete_token = str(result_tokentype) + " " + str(result_accesstoken)`
Use the variable as a parameter-value:
`headers = {"Authorization": complete_token, "X-User-Groups": "app_create", "Content-Type": "application/json" }`
I can now use this token to make other GET requests.
Do you have an idea how to check if the request is valid (and which module is probably needed)?

Comment: Make the request and check the response, that is pretty much all to it. Use Graph API Explorer to explore what all you can get from APIs. Read the FB API docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer:

I've put the whole output of my POST request into the variable `result`.
The structure of my token has to be like this: "Bearer tokenstring".
So I put the type into the variable `result_tokentype`and the token string into the variable `result_accesstoken`.
Finally I put them together into the variable `accessToken`:

```
result_tokentype = result["token_type"]
result_accesstoken = result["access_token"]
accessToken = str(result_tokentype) + " " + str(result_accesstoken)
```

Now that I have the complete string in the right structure, I can use this variable for the next requests, e.g.:

```
url = "https://myurl.com"
headers = {"Authorization": accessToken, "key1": "value1", "Content-Type": "application/json" }
conn.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
```

This worked the best for me, here.